# IPN page still not working PHP mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, paypal, paypal-ipn

Getting pretty frustrated with this now. Followed the Paypal guide exactly and still not getting what I need.

*Inserting the values into the database from the IPN*

**Here's the step by step guide:**

[**1:** Plan your IPN Solution for both backend and listener: Decide which language you are going to use and review the PayPal IPN listener code samples. Plan what backend tasks need to be done for each type of IPN message (IPN Transaction Types) received.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) **Complete**

*Using php and going to insert txn_id, payment_status and user_id to begin with*

---

**2:** Implement and verify the PayPal request-response part of your listener: Create only the PayPal request-response part of your listener to verify that the required handshaking is working, without any backend code attached.] **Complete**

[*Using sample code that paypal provide from github*](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples)

**IPN Simulator outputting this:** 
[image]

---

**3:** Implement the listener backend functionality: Temporarily comment out the request-response handshaking part of the listener code since it is already verified as working, and then implement and verify that the backend part of your listener code is working.] **Complete**

*Used this form to test my query for inserting to the db:*

```
<form action="**********" method="POST">
  <input name="mc_gross" type="hidden" value="500.00" />
  <input name="custom" type="hidden" value="some custom data" />
  <input name="address_status" type="hidden" value="confirmed" />
  <input name="item_number1" type="hidden" value="6" />
  <input name="item_number2" type="hidden" value="4" />
  <input name="payer_id" type="hidden" value="FW5W7ZUC3T4KL" />
  <input name="tax" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="address_street" type="hidden" value="1234 Rock Road" />
  <input name="payment_date" type="hidden" value="14:55 15 Jan 07 2005 PST" />
  <input name="payment_status" type="hidden" value="Completed" />
  <input name="address_zip" type="hidden" value="12345" />
  <input name="mc_shipping" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="mc_handling" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="first_name" type="hidden" value="Jason" />
  <input name="last_name" type="hidden" value="Anderson" />
  <input name="mc_fee" type="hidden" value="0.02" />
  <input name="address_name" type="hidden" value="Jason Anderson" />
  <input name="notify_version" type="hidden" value="1.6" />
  <input name="payer_status" type="hidden" value="verified" />
  <input name="business" type="hidden" value="paypal@emailaddress.com" />
  <input name="address_country" type="hidden" value="United States" />
  <input name="num_cart_items" type="hidden" value="2" />
  <input name="mc_handling1" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="mc_handling2" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="address_city" type="hidden" value="Los Angeles" />
  <input name="verify_sign" type="hidden" value="AlUbUcinRR5pIo2KwP4xjo9OxxHMAi6.s6AES.4Z6C65yv1Ob2eNqrHm" />
  <input name="mc_shipping1" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="mc_shipping2" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="tax1" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="tax2" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="txn_id" type="hidden" value="TESTER" />
  <input name="payment_type" type="hidden" value="instant" />
  <input name="last_name=Borduin" type="hidden" />
  <input name="payer_email" type="hidden" value="test@domain.com" />
  <input name="item_name1" type="hidden" value="Rubber+clog" />
  <input name="address_state" type="hidden" value="CA" />
  <input name="payment_fee" type="hidden" value="0.02" />
  <input name="item_name2" type="hidden" value="Roman sandal" />
  <input name="invoice" type="hidden" value="123456" />
  <input name="quantity" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input name="quantity1" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input name="receiver_id" type="hidden" value="5HRS8SCK9NSJ2" />
  <input name="quantity2" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input name="txn_type" type="hidden" value="web_accept" />
  <input name="mc_gross_1" type="hidden" value="0.01" />
  <input name="mc_currency" type="hidden" value="USD" />
  <input name="mc_gross_2" type="hidden" value="0.01" />
  <input name="payment_gross" type="hidden" value="0.02" />
  <input name="subscr_id" type="hidden" value="PP-1234" />
  <input name="test" type="submit" value="test" />
</form>
```

### *It worked beautifully*

**4:** Test the listener: Uncomment the request-response code to test and verify that both the request-response handshaking and backend processes are working together as expected using the various different levels of recommended IPN testing methods, including the PayPal Sandbox environment and the IPN simulator tool. **Incomplete**

*Put the query and the sample code together but it is not inserting into the database*

Here is my IPN listener Code:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php'
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);
// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    // assign posted variables to local variables

    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $id = $_POST['custom'];

        if($payment_status=="Completed"){
        $txn_id_check = $mysqli->query("SELECT `transaction_id` FROM `payment` WHERE `transaction_id`='$txn_id'");;
        if($txn_id_check->num_rows != 1) {  
                    $query = "INSERT INTO `payment` (`transaction_id`, `payment_status`, `users_id`) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
                    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
                    $statement->bind_param('ssi',$txn_id, $payment_status, $id);
                    if($statement->execute()){
                    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
                    }else{
                    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
                    }
                    $statement->close();
        }
    }
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
?>
```

---

I have also followed this guide [on how to create an IPN page](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) but the same results persist

**Note, this is my ipn.log file after 1 simulated IPN:**

```
[2015-10-21 13:49 America/Chicago] HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 882
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 for IPN payload: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=echeck&payment_date=Wed+Oct+21+2015+19%3A14%3A37+GMT%2B0100+%28GMT+Summer+Time%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name=something&item_number=AK-1234&quantity=1&shipping=3.04&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross1=12.34&txn_type=web_accept&txn_id=602383467&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AhVMpD1906o6kD2.tixEm-LUc.gf
[2015-10-21 13:49 America/Chicago] HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 18:49:22 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=e1HUZ1OWMNI1uP_J_wM_lNec93JAFurXcAwAzN1nuotTGpdRkUHMUn__h3D2JJuFN3K_6r8CLlTouCQd7MC07PjGHuLIJnpobt6AT6qTUJianiXIibJ8pMpfXC1mWpnYWZ4TF5ydp6hbjHvgj2oe0xsNSQD_IJ_ChEZqvi9EDAQZvpJJAw7HBIyrRNnEDUfsOr_M-sPRIHNQNXc0XdgNaHrWmozcxuSgUxocug7ClZKjoPymv8tqm8My5LMoZlQoMMaVoNFyptiymVktHNkRcO9cYi-aPI4ymcTb8iGWHLDHR9Sxte04ae7ap05Qi7dGj79RAGaYJAvDUOAOSjmFlfyM4qStFz2NFwi3WsVIZe4J-kPZR7ZlwkhlJyq82i5iM8otsWuSUYp9G5cJyrt7u7Cc8hYDDLAEx7cqfj7TR3LzBNcIHktt7Aye4yC; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Sat, 18-Oct-2025 18:49:22 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Fri, 20-Oct-2017 18:49:22 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.108.11.1445453362642214; path=/; expires=Fri, 13-Oct-45 18:49:22 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Paypal-Debug-Id: 892222cc992c5
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D853419862; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.128.11.1445453362627267; path=/; expires=Fri, 13-Oct-45 18:49:22 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

VERIFIED
[2015-10-21 13:49 America/Chicago] Verified IPN: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=echeck&payment_date=Wed+Oct+21+2015+19%3A14%3A37+GMT%2B0100+%28GMT+Summer+Time%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name=something&item_number=AK-1234&quantity=1&shipping=3.04&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross1=12.34&txn_type=web_accept&txn_id=602383467&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AhVMpD1906o6kD2.tixEm-LUc.gf
```

Comment: Follow the steps outlined in this [guide on how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) and you should be able to track down the problem.

Comment: @AndrewAngell that's exactly the same as the PayPal guide just less specific. ( already been through it )

Comment: It's not, really, and there have been many similar questions on SO that resolved their issue following that guide.  If you don't want to go through the steps, though, that's your choice.

Comment: @AndrewAngell have you read through my question? I have literally followed paypals more in depth version of the one you linked. I have followed it also and still no luck

Comment: Yes, I have read your question.  My guide is not the same as what you've outlined here.  What you're showing here gets you up to a certain point.  My guide is about how to test once you get to that point and you aren't getting what you expect.  The first step being creating your own simulator so you can see the result in the browser.

Comment: @AndrewAngell read my question. I created my own simulator.

Comment: So when you run your own simulator and you can see the result in a browser, what do you get?  You say the data isn't showing up..?  The sql result must be returning something.  I see that you have some general debug steps in there for that, but what is getting output?

Comment: Using the form that I created, I commented out the rest of the code apart from my query, and it inserted the values into the database

Comment: Ok, if it's not working when you use their simulator then you'll need to save log files or email yourself notifications of mysql errors that must be occurring.  It's possible some sort of special character or something in the data is causing a sql query conflict.  The best thing to do would be to take a look at your server log after using the PayPal simulator. What is it showing?

Comment: I'm checking the error log, however it is empty, send a few simulated IPN's but no errors. I'm using `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` am I correct in doing so?

Comment: Well, that's the thing, you won't see any errors like that on screen.  You'll need to catch errors and log them or add some sort of general debug steps in the code.  For example, send yourself an email at certain points within the code to see if the steps you think are getting reached are in fact getting reached.

Comment: Got it working!! @AndrewAngell thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used email error handling to check what I was doing wrong

```
function error_handler($number,$message,$file,$line,$vars){

    $email = "<p>An error ($number) occured on line <strong>$line</strong> and in the file:
    $file.<p>$message</p>";
    $email .= "<pre>" . print_r($vars) . "</pre>";
    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    error_log($email, 1, 'myemail@gmail.com', $headers);
}

set_error_handler('error_handler');
```

It then showed me that I was missing a semi colon

```
inlude 'connect.php'
```

so

inlude 'connect.php';

And that I had two semicolons here:

```
("SELECT `transaction_id` FROM `payment` WHERE `transaction_id`='$txn_id'");;
```

so

```
 ("SELECT `transaction_id` FROM `payment` WHERE `transaction_id`='$txn_id'");
```

Comment: Glad you got it worked out.  I guess I'm a little confused, though, because that's something you should have seen if you were hitting your script with your own simulator from within a browser.

Comment: Well that's the thing, when I created my simulator it worked perfectly, when I transitioned over to paypals IPN simulator it wouldn't work. I must have accidentally punched in them errors when copying and pasting, or something stupid